# desktop applications bandwidth consumption, if there is such

Tags: web-applications, desktop, bandwidth

I'm really confused as to why the browser while loading some pages buffers a lot when I'm having quite few desktop applications running.Do desktop applications like MS word, excel, etc... consume bandwidth or affect it in any way?

Comment: I assume chrome..?? :P

Comment: LOL. does it matter? seriously?

Comment: It's not the bandwidth that matters. It's the processes. Have you ever checked the task manager when you have a browser with multiple tabs, the task consumes a lot of memory. The point being that, it's not a bandwidth issue, it's a process issue. Rendering games or websites using SWF or Flash or anything that is resource intensive, the browser tends to render things slower. Close all your applications and check. Way faster. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thanks. I totally understand that it's a matter of CPU allocation to processes but how do I determine the CPU consumption of a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

If your memory is tight and your browser needs extra memory, some memory pages allocated to other applications might be paged out. If CPU is tight, your browser will be competing for time slices and so on for network, disk IO. As far as bandwidth is concerned, there is no reason word or excel would consume any, unless they acquire data from a db or run a web query (but then you would know it)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now, you got me thinking as to how would I know the memory allocated to a specific desktop application or program and does it change every time I open or use it, say for example MS word then I create a new word file? Second is, similarly, how do I know the CPU consumption? Is it constant? lastly, given that you said it depends on memory and CPU allocation, do a lesser available space and a busy CPU decrease bandwidth? Im sorry if I ask to many.. please bear with this kid. Thanks. :)

Comment: To determine memory consumption and cpu usage, use the task manager. Memory and cpu utilization will vary depending on how much data is loaded and what manipulation your are doing such as find and replace. Try creating a large excel file with say 50000 rows and sum or sort. You should see a significant increase in cpu utilization.

Comment: ahhhh. I see. so, do lesser available space and a busy CPU decrease bandwidth?